# Understanding the output of scipy.stats.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to build a multidimensional gaussian model using `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`. I am trying to use the output of `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf()` to figure out if a test value fits reasonable well in the observed distribution.

From what I understand, high values indicate a better fit to the given model and low values otherwise.

However, in my dataset, I see extremely large `PDF(x)` results, which lead me to question if I understand things correctly. The area under the PDF curve must be 1, so very large values are hard to comprehend.

For e.g., consider:

`x = [-0.0007569417915494715, -0.01394295997613827, 0.000982078369890444, -0.03633664354397629, -0.03730583036106844, 0.013920453054506978, -0.08115836865224338, -0.07208494497398354, -0.06255237023298793, -0.0531888840386906, -0.006823760545565131]`

`mean = [0.01663645201261102, 0.07800335614699873, 0.016291452384234965, 0.012042931155488702, 0.0042637244100103885, 0.016531331606477996, -0.021702714746699842, -0.05738646649459681, 0.00921296058625439, 0.027940994009345254, 0.07548111758006244]`

`covariance = [[0.07921927017771506, 0.04780185747873293, 0.0788086850274493, 0.054129466248481264, 0.018799028456661045, 0.07523731808137141, 0.027682748950487425, -0.007296954729572955, 0.07935165417756569, 0.0569381100965656, 0.04185848489472492], [0.04780185747873293, 0.052300105044833595, 0.047749467098423544, 0.03254872837949123, 0.010582358713999951, 0.045792252383799206, 0.01969282984717051, -0.006089301208961258, 0.05067712814145293, 0.03146214776997301, 0.04452949330387575], [0.0788086850274493, 0.047749467098423544, 0.07841809405745602, 0.05374461924031552, 0.01871005609017673, 0.07487015790787396, 0.02756781074862818, -0.007327131572569985, 0.07895548129950304, 0.056417456686115544, 0.04181063355048408], [0.054129466248481264, 0.03254872837949123, 0.05374461924031552, 0.04538801863296238, 0.015795381235224913, 0.05055944754764062, 0.02017033995851422, -0.006505939129684573, 0.05497361331950649, 0.043858860182247515, 0.029356699144606032], [0.018799028456661045, 0.010582358713999951, 0.01871005609017673, 0.015795381235224913, 0.016260640022897347, 0.015459548918222347, 0.0064542528152879705, -0.0016656858963383602, 0.018761682220822192, 0.015361512546799405, 0.009832025009280924], [0.07523731808137141, 0.045792252383799206, 0.07487015790787396, 0.05055944754764062, 0.015459548918222347, 0.07207012779105286, 0.026330967917717253, -0.006907504360835279, 0.0753380831201204, 0.05335128471397023, 0.03998397595850863], [0.027682748950487425, 0.01969282984717051, 0.02756781074862818, 0.02017033995851422, 0.0064542528152879705, 0.026330967917717253, 0.020837940236441078, -0.003320408544812026, 0.027859582829638897, 0.01967636950969646, 0.017105000942890598], [-0.007296954729572955, -0.006089301208961258, -0.007327131572569985, -0.006505939129684573, -0.0016656858963383602, -0.006907504360835279, -0.003320408544812026, 0.024529061074105817, -0.007869287828047853, -0.006228903058681195, -0.0058974553248417995], [0.07935165417756569, 0.05067712814145293, 0.07895548129950304, 0.05497361331950649, 0.018761682220822192, 0.0753380831201204, 0.027859582829638897, -0.007869287828047853, 0.08169291677188911, 0.05731196406065222, 0.04450058445993234], [0.0569381100965656, 0.03146214776997301, 0.056417456686115544, 0.043858860182247515, 0.015361512546799405, 0.05335128471397023, 0.01967636950969646, -0.006228903058681195, 0.05731196406065222, 0.05064023101024737, 0.02830810316675855], [0.04185848489472492, 0.04452949330387575, 0.04181063355048408, 0.029356699144606032, 0.009832025009280924, 0.03998397595850863, 0.017105000942890598, -0.0058974553248417995, 0.04450058445993234, 0.02830810316675855, 0.040658283674780395]]`

For this, if I compute `y = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean, cov);`
the result is `342562705.3859754`.

How could this be the case? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. The `probability density function` **can be** larger than 1 at a specific point. It's the integral than must be equal to 1.

The idea that `pdf < 1` is correct for discrete variables. However, for continuous ones, the `pdf` *is not* a probability. It's a value that is *integrated to* a probability. That is, the integral from minus infinity to infinity, in all dimensions, is equal to `1`.

Comment: So, intuitively how would I explain this? The PDF curve extends into the negative quadrant too, such that the area under the curve still comes up to 1? If I am right, the negative values should not impact the area in any way. Sorry if I am vague and wrong, I am just trying to explain it in my head

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I need to think about multiple dimensions too! So with the above case, is the PDF still an indicator of the degree of fit with the model? For e.g., will it be always true that large values are good fits and small values are not? Identifying a threshold for this can be handled empirically, but does this premise hold true always?

Comment: @jamie: your dataset should have many points in areas with high pdf, and few points is areas with low pdf. However, there is no single metric for evaluating how well a number of points fit a distribution.